# Passing arrays produced in a function between classes

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++. Here is my problem details.

I have these files in my code

main.cpp
Source1.cpp
Source1.h
Source2.cpp
Source2.h

Source 1 and source 2 cpp and h files represent two classes ClassA and ClassB. I have a function in class 1 which calculates an array AE[N]. Now I output this to my main function. Until then it works perfect. Now in my Class B I have another array which is AB[N] which takes AE[N] values calculated from previous classA function. However the correct values are not passed from Class A to Class B (instead 0 is being passed).

So how do I correctly pass the array values from class to class in this instance?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot `return` function-local C-style arrays.  Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Please include [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you did.